# How can I check for a C++ compiler in Makefile.PL?

Tags: c++, perl

In a Perl module/distribution/package, how can I test for the presence of a functioning C++ compiler in "Makefile.PL" and halt if the C++ compiler is not functioning?

Comment: You could try to compile something, that will certainly halt if there is no compiler...

Comment: Yes, it's possible to code a solution within Makefile.PL. However, I would like to check whether there is a prepackaged solution. This would make it robuster.

Comment: I don't know perl, but you can use `dpkg --list | grep compiler | grep -ie c++ -ie cpp` to get the list of installed c++ compilers.

Comment: I presume you want to check for a specific compiler, e.g. g++?

Comment: No I want to check whether there is a C++ compiler or not.

Answer (score 2):

[ExtUtils::CppGuess](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aCppGuess) was written for exactly this purpose. It's not perfect, but will work on most common platforms.

Comment: Nice suggestion which I wasn't aware of, but unfortunately that has about 10% test failures on cpan testers, which makes me concerned about how far it can be trusted to predict the compiler correctly on an unknown system.

Comment: I would expect most of those to be simply a lack of a C++ compiler, and TBH expecting a perfectly portable solution here is not realistic. It seems to work most of the time, and when it doesn't I'm sure patches are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you could do what autoconfig does as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/C_002b_002b-Compiler.html). They look for the shell variable `CXX` then `CCC` then the binary `g++` in the path then `c++` in the path. One they do not test for is clang++ or microsoft's compilers, but this functionality could be easily duplicated in perl.

```
    @path = split(/:/, $ENV{"PATH"} );
    $CXX = $ENV{"CXX"} || $ENV{"CCC"} || undef;
    if (!defined($CXX)){
            foreach my $path(reverse(@path)){
                    my $test = $path . "/g++";
                    if ( -e $test){
                            $CXX = $test ;
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
    print $CXX . "\n"
```

If other compilers need to be looked for, you could easily modify the code to test for them as well by adding aditional if statements. Aditionally if you wanted to search places other than the the system `PATH`, you could append possible directories to `@path`.

Answer (score -1):

I would second Mohit Jain's comment in recommending the use of grep to find a compiler. You'd have to be careful to get as few false positives/negatives as possible, but it should be doable. The specific implementation of this would change based on your environment, of course.

Of course, if you are looking for a specific compiler you can check for files and such specific to that compiler, but judging by the lack of such details in your question you appear to be looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Mohit's suggestion was to use dkpg but that is only going to work in a Debian based Linux distribution. What about RedHat or Solaris or Windows, etc? The best option is to just run the compiler your module requires to see if it exists, e.g. `g++ --version` and check the output.

Comment: @imran I am assuming that the asker wants a general solution - that is, they simply wish to find _a_ compiler, not any specific one - due to the lack of details in the question regarding a specific compiler. Grepping (or otherwise searching, I suppose, if you're dealing with Windows or something) for indications that a compiler is present, while not ideal, is the best I can think of for the general case.

Comment: grep'ing through the output of `dpkg` is **not** a general, portable solution - it applies only to Debian-based Linux systems, and even on those it only finds ones installed through the package manager. It wouldn't find ones compiled from source manually.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The unwritten rider here is to use a similar tool where grep is not available. Hence the "The specific implementation of this would change based on your environment" bit in my answer.